# Inject multiple 3rd party Javascript files in gulp project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, gulp-inject

I'm new to gulp, and I have a project running that produces a HTML5 QR code scanner with some functionalities around it. For this scanner, I need several 3rd party Javascript files. When I'm running "gulp serve", there is no problem, the camera does what I order it to do, but when I'm running "gulp build", it doesn't find the javascript files, and I think the reason for this is that bower does not inject these files into the main "app.js".

I have tried to adapt my "scripts.js" - file in the gulp-directory like this:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

module.exports = function(options) {
  gulp.task('scripts', function () {
      return gulp.src([options.src + '/app/**/*.js', '!' + options.src + '/app/scan-camera/jsqrcodescanner/*.js'])
      //.pipe($.jshint())
      //.pipe($.jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
      .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
      .pipe($.size());
  });
};
```

but without result... the javascript files are in the projectname/src/app/scan-camera/jsqrcodescanner - directory. Does anyone has a solution for this?